# mat-checkbox: why would the change $event ever be falsy?

Tags: angular-material

Code from the angular material component [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#selection):

```html
    <mat-checkbox (change)="$event ? masterToggle() : null"
                  [checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected()"
                  [indeterminate]="selection.hasValue() && !isAllSelected()">
    </mat-checkbox>
```

Why does the `change` handler check if `$event` is truthy - and why return `null` in that case?

In my [Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gdqmw7?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-selection-example.html), it also seems to work without that code. Am I missing something?

Comment: This is master checkbox. It can be checked/unchecked  from a checkbox list. that time $event is null or undefined.

Comment: @DindayalDhakar I think you are wrong: see the [Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gdqmw7?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-selection-example.html). It also works without that code, no matter if I click the master or any detail checkboxes.